# Convert Character Date format to R Date

Tags: r

I have data in Character format like 'Feb-20'. I need to convert it to '2020-02-29' R Date format. Code should be generic to convert any month and return last day of month.

```
repmonth  <- 'Feb-20'
```

Comment: what abt year? is it fixed 2020?

Comment: Why is it 29th though?!

Comment: Year can be changed. It will be last day of month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `strptime`:

```
   strptime('Feb-20',format="%b-%d", tz="UTC")

[1] "2020-02-20 UTC"
```

Or using `lubridate` as @Neem Kamal suggests:

```
lubridate::ymd(paste0("2020-","Feb-20"))
```

**EDIT**:

To return the last day of the month:

```
lubridate::ceiling_date(strptime('Feb-20',format="%b-%d", tz="UTC"),"month") -1
[1] "2020-02-29 23:59:59 UTC"
```

Works for March as well:

```
lubridate::ceiling_date(strptime('Mar-20',format="%b-%d", tz="UTC"),"month") -1
[1] "2020-03-31 23:59:59 UTC"
```

Drawbacks: It returns time too.

Comment: lubridate::ymd(paste0("2020-","Feb-20")) **tidyverse way**

Comment: It should be last day of month 29 for Feb-20

Comment: It should be 29.  2020-02-29

Comment: Check EDIT 2. I am not aware of a way to generalise. You could test that the month is Feb using `month` and only do the `-1` for that row.

Answer (score 0):

29 is fixed?
You could use the lubridate package:

```
lubridate::myd(paste0('Feb-20','-29'))
```

Comment: 29 is not fixed. It should be last day of month

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
library(lubridate)
repmonth  <- 'Feb-20'
rollback(ymd(paste0("2020-",repmonth) ) + month(1), roll_to_first = F)
```

The above will give what exactly you are looking for. **The last day of the month** whether it's leap year or not.

Comment: @NelsonGon Please suggest.